# action.setCallback not being executed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a issue where in my action.setCallback is not being run.

I already checked the debug logs and the apex methods are not being called

So basically this is what happens
1.) User click submit button.
2.) Button run a application event to call a file upload validation
3.) File Upload validation run - File is valid
4.) once file upload is complete
5.) Will call another event to call a Task creation method

This is my Code

I will just post the important parts

```
    //helper.submitCycle(component,event);
    var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:PC_Roche_UploadDoc_Start_Event");
    appEvent.setParams({
        "parentId" : component.get("v.cycleRecordId")
    });
    appEvent.fire();
    //helper.submitCycle(component,event);
```

This event will call this helper

```
    uploadFile : function(component, event , helper){

    if(component.get('v.isFileValid') != undefined){
        component.set('v.isFileValid', undefined);
    }
    console.log('UPLOAD Files ->');
    var parentId = event.getParam("parentId");

    var masterId = event.getParam("masterId");
    // var masterId = 'a060w000000AcCLAA0';

    var files = component.get('v.files');
    var filesLength = component.get('v.files').length;
    var self = this;

    if(filesLength != 0){
        for(let i=0; i < filesLength; i++){
            let file = files[i];
            var fr = new FileReader();
            var self = this;
            fr.onloadend = function(e) {
                let fileContents = e.target.result;
                let base64Mark = 'base64,';
                let dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64Mark) + base64Mark.length;
                fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);
                self.upload(component, file, fileContents,parentId,masterId);
            };
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
    else{
        this.closeAndRefreshModal(component);
    }
},

    upload : function(component,file,fileContents,parentId,masterId) {

    var self = this;
    self.fileValidation(component,file.name,file.type);
    var action = component.get('c.saveTheChunk');
    console.log('file.name>>>>>' + file.name);
    console.log('parentID ->' + parentId);
    console.log('masterId ->' + masterId);

    action.setParams({
        "parentId": parentId,
        "fileName": file.name,
        "base64Data": encodeURIComponent(fileContents), 
        "contentType": file.type,
        "masterId" : masterId
    });
    console.log('UPLOAD AFTER PARAM -> ');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        var isFileValid = component.get('v.isFileValid');
        console.log('ISFILEVALID -> ' + isFileValid);
        if (state === "SUCCESS" && isFileValid != false) {
            console.log('UPLOAD SUCCESS - >');
            //this.closeAndRefreshModal(component);
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR" && isFileValid != false) {
            console.log('ERROR - >>>>>');
            this.throwError(component);
        }
    });
    console.log('ENQUE ACTION 2 -> ');
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

fileValidation : function(component,fileName,fileType){
    console.log('FILE VALIDATION -> ');
    console.log('fileName -> ' + fileName);
    console.log('fileType -> ' + fileType);

    var action = component.get('c.fileValidation');

    console.log('action -> ' + action);

    action.setParams({
        "fileName" : fileName,
        "fileType" : fileType
    });

    console.log('AFTER PARAMS -> ');
    alert('Test');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('STATE -> ' + state);
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var isFileNotAllowed = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('isError -> ' + isFileNotAllowed);
            if(isFileNotAllowed == true){
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                component.set('v.isFileValid', false);
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    title: "Error!",
                    message: "There is a problem in creating online form, Uploaded file is not supported.",
                    type: "error"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            }
        }
    });
    console.log('ENQUE ACTION -> 1');
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

So basically what happens to me is it gets stuck in the calling of action.setCallback. The Only way for it to run is clicking the submit button again.

Thank you

Comment: can you minimize the amount of code and create a [minimal reproduceable code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to better highlight the issue

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this issue using Javascript Promise.

Here are some documentation in regards to the use of javascript promise in Lightning components

https://rajvakati.com/2018/05/29/using-promise-in-lightning-component/
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2016/12/javascript-promises-in-lightning_30.html